# Setting Qtableview.setSpan with pyside?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to setSpan on QTableView using setSpan() api but unable to achieve it using example snippet **`self.ui.tableWidget_Result.setSpan(1,1,2,0)`**

My table looks like attached image :

[image]

I want to arrange columns cells with same data in one. I am getting error

> QTableView::setSpan: invalid span given: ( 1 , 1 , 2 , 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i got this resolved and was facing the understanding issue.
**`self.ui.tableWidget_Result.setSpan(1,1,2,1)`**

Where 2 is how much row will be spanned over how many columns i.e. 1 in my case